# Как осуществить поиск через Repository?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

У пользователя есть атрибутом `Роль`, по умолчанию `TENANT`, с помощью запроса задаем ему `LANDLORD` и в таблицу `HOUSE` он теперь добавляет квартиру с различными атрибутами: описание, цена, city_id и другие. Этот пользователь захотел снять с себя статус `LANDLORD`, удалить свои квартиры из нашей базы и снова стать просто `TENANT`, как мне квартирам, которые, если у него были - поставить status INACTIVE? Я только понял как ему роль присвоить, а как найти квартиры, которые ему принадлежали - не догадался. Мой вариант с поиском по id_landlord почему-то не сработал. Прикрепил фотографию того, какие есть атрибуты у House и User.

Заготовка кода выглядит так:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('landlord:write')")
    public void TenantPostAdd(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        user.setRole(Role.TENANT);
        House house = houseRepository.findById_landlord(id); - не работает
        house.setStatus(Status.INACTIVELY);
    }
```

HouseRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface HouseRepository extends JpaRepository<House, Long> {
    House findById_landlord(@Param("id_landlord") House house);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[FULL CODE](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent/tree/master/src/main/java/task/homerent).

Comment: На чистом SQL это будет CTE, удаляющий связанные записи, и основной запрос, изменяющий родительскую. А как это будет выглядеть средствами фреймворка (если он вообще способен такое отобразить) - я даже представить не могу.

Comment: В принципе ничто не мешает сперва откорректировать запись юзера, а потом безусловно удалить все записи о квартирах, если у связанной записи пользователя статус НЕ landlord. *Слышал о том, что в крупных компания их не удаляют, а что-то со связями делают, удаляют или нет..., вроде, данные сохраняются и , если нужно, то связи быстро восстанавливают.* В приличных системах НИКАКАЯ информация не удаляется. Пометить как неактуальную, снести в архив и т.п....

Comment: Да я вообще за закрытие вопроса - только долго сомневался, по какой из двух последних причин... и мои комментарии уж точно не тянут на ответ, тем более полезный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам смог сделать, надеюсь, что достаточно корректно происходят действия.
Пояснения: получил id, нашёл этого user'а, присвоил ему роль "TENANT", дальше нашёл дома, к котором он относится, выставил у них статус и всё сохранил. Правда сохранение не особо нравится, но на скорую руку именно так.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('landlord:write')")
    public void landlordPostAdd(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        user.setRole(Role.TENANT);
        Iterable<House> house = houseRepository.findById_landlord(id);
        for (House a : house) {
            a.setStatus(Status.INACTIVELY);
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }
```